# Find one side of a triangle using trigonometry impossible question

Tags: trigonometry

In the isosceles triangle $ABC$ where $a=|BC|,\ b=|CA|,\ c=|AB|$ and angle at corner $A = x$
and angle at corner $B = y$ and angle at corner $C = z$ ($z>90$ degrees)

$a=b=4$ ; $\sin z = 3/8$

Find value of $c$ (which is side $|AB|$ as stated above)

My friends father is math teacher in high school and he couldn't even solve it,
can anyone help?

Comment: If the triangle is isosceles there *must be* two equal sides and two equal angles. Why do they **all** are different? What are the equal sides...? (I already know which one, and you **should** also...)\

Comment: a=b=4 DonAntonio

Comment: Very vague question!!We can ofcourse find $c$ in terms of $a,b$ and the angle $z$...Infact the answer is $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos z$...also,$a=b$ as the triangle is isosceles...

Comment: DonAntonio can you help me solve this question

Comment: $ c/4 =\sin ( \frac12 \sin^ {-1} {\frac38} ) $

Answer (score 2):

Simply use law of cosine:
$$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos z} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab(-\sqrt{1-\sin^2 z})} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 2ab\sqrt{1-\sin^2 z}}.$$

EDIT: Because $z> \pi/2$, $\cos(z) <0 \implies \cos(z) = -\sqrt{1-\sin^2z}$

Comment: I cant calculate that is it sqrt 32 - 4 * sqrt 55?

Comment: Grixor can you help me calculate that one I get it to 32 - 4 * sqrt 55 but I think its wrong

Comment: @Vladimir Please give the values of the sides and angles in the triangle so that we can help you better...you must try to state the question exactly as it was....

Comment: a=b=4 and sin z = 3/8 are all values I promise!

Comment: @Vladimir $c=\sqrt{32-32\sqrt{55}/8}$

Comment: You want the negative (internal) square root because cosine is negative in quadrant two.

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you! I glossed over that fact!

Answer (score 0):

@grixor's answer, using the law of cosines is (currently, almost) correct, but perhaps uses a tool that is not yet in the student's toolbox.  We can derive this result from the problem as given.

Extend $\overline{AC}$ until it intersects the perpendicular to $\overline{AC}$ through $B$ and call this intersection $D$.  Call the measure of angle $BCD$ $\theta$ and note that $\theta = 180^\circ - z$.  Then the right triangle $BCD$ supplies \begin{align}
    \sin \theta &= \frac{|BD|}{a}  \\
    \cos \theta &= \frac{|CD|}{a}  \text{.}  \\
\end{align}
Using supplementary angle identities, we have $\sin \theta = \sin z = |BD|/a$ and $\cos \theta = -\cos z = |CD|/a$.  Rewriting in terms of the quantities we want, $|BD| = a \sin z$ and $|CD| = -a \cos z$.

Now shift attention to the right triangle $ABD$.  From this triangle and the Pythagorean theorem, we see \begin{align}
    c^2 &= |BD|^2 + (b+|CD|)^2  \\
        &= (a \sin z)^2 + (b - a \cos z)^2  \\
        &= a^2 \sin^2 z + b^2 - 2 a b \cos z + a^2 \cos^2 z  \\
        &= a^2( \sin^2 z + \cos^2 z) +b^2 - 2 a b \cos z  \\
        &= a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b \cos z  \text{.}
\end{align}  We have used the identity $\sin^2 z + \cos^2 z = 1$.  We use it again to get $\cos z = -\sqrt{1 - \sin^2 z}$.  (We know we want the negative root because we know $z$ is in the second quadrant, so cosine is negative.)  Collecting our algebra together, we have  $$  c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2 a b \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 z}  \text{.}  $$

We're given $a = b = 4$ and $\sin z = 3/8$, so we can evaluate:\begin{align}
    c^2 &= 4^2 + 4^2 + 2 \cdot 4^2 \sqrt{1 - (3/8)^2}  \\
        &= 32 + 32\sqrt{\frac{64-9}{64}}  \\
        &= 32 + 32\sqrt{55/64}  \text{.}
\end{align}  Now we know $c = \sqrt{32 + 32\sqrt{55/64}}$.